# How to properly send a body in a request using android retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm not getting the same result I have in POSTMAN working with the Retrofit Android lib. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Below is my code that I use to call the API

```
    @Override
    protected Response doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Response<UserModel> response;
        try {
            LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel("password", mEmail, mPassword, "Mobile", "123@abc");
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            ServiceAPI serviceAPI = retrofit.create(ServiceAPI.class);
            Call<UserModel> call = serviceAPI.getToken(loginModel);

            try{
                response = call.execute();
                if (response.body() == null) {
                    Log.d(getString(R.string.app_name), response.errorBody().toString());
                    return response;
                } else {
                    return response;
                }
            }catch ( IOException e){
                Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
            }


            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Below the interface code

```
public interface ServiceAPI {
    @POST("Token")
    Call<UserModel> getToken(@Body LoginModel loginModel);
}
```

And the result is:
[image: ErroBody]

Class LoginModel.java

```
public class LoginModel {

@SerializedName("grant_type")
private String grantType;
private String username;
private String password;
@SerializedName("client_id")
private String clientId;
@SerializedName("client_secret")
private String clientSecret;

public LoginModel(String grantType, String username, String password, String clientId, String clientSecret) {
    this.grantType = grantType;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.clientId = clientId;
    this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
}
```

}

With PostMan the result is different, getting the Token correction.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your api

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@Post("Token")
Call<UserModel> getToken(@Field("grant_type") String grantType),
                         @Field("username") String userName,
                         @Field("password") String password
                         // etc
                       );
```

And your api call

```
Call<UserModel> call = serviceAPI.getToken("password", mEmail, mPassword, ...);
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me! But I still have the same result. I have edited my question according to your answer.
I am still unsuccessful. Do you have any cards up your sleeve?

Comment: @Duk My answer was actually wrong. When I took a look at the Postman screenshot I saw a json object and thought it was the request body, when in fact it was the response. Looking more carefully I can see the API does not accept a json body.